# Strange influence of implicit Mapper on implicit Mapped parameter

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

Suppose I have container-marker

```
case class TypedString[T](value: String)
```

and partial function trick

```
abstract class PartFunc[Actual <: HList] {
    val poly: Poly

    def apply[L1 <: HList](l: L1)(implicit
                                  mapped: Mapped.Aux[Actual, TypedString, L1],
                                  mapper: Mapper[poly.type, L1]): L1 = l
}
```

Poly for Mapper

```
object f extends (TypedString ~>> String) {
    def apply[T](s : TypedString[T]) = s.value
}
```

and result method

```
def func[Actual <: HList] = new PartFunc[Actual] {
    val poly = f
}
```

Example of usage:

```
func[
    Int :: String :: HNil
](TypedString[Int]("42") :: TypedString[String]("hello") :: HNil)
```

This code fails at compile time because compiler cannot find `Mapped` implicit parameter:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter mapped: 
    shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapped[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]],nottogether.MapperTest.TypedString]{type Out = shapeless.::[nottogether.MapperTest.TypedString[Int],shapeless.::[nottogether.MapperTest.TypedString[String],shapeless.HNil]]}
        ](TypedString[Int]("42") :: TypedString[String]("hello") :: HNil)
```

But if we remove `Mapper` implicit parameter from `PartFunc.apply(...)` signature all works fine. So I have no idea why and how `Mapper` influence on `Mapped`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler complains about `Mapped` while the actual issue is with `Mapper`. I am not sure why, but there seems to be going something wrong with getting a `Mapped` for the singleton type `poly.type` when `poly` is an abstract value or a constructor argument of `PartFunc`.

A solution would be to make `poly` a `P <: Poly` and passing the singleton type along with `Actual`  when we create the `PartFunc` :

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist.{Mapped, Mapper}
import poly.~>>

abstract class PartFunc[Actual <: HList, P <: Poly] {
  val poly: P
  def apply[L1 <: HList](l: L1)(implicit
    mapped: Mapped.Aux[Actual, TypedString, L1],
    mapper: Mapper[P, L1]
  ): mapper.Out = mapper(l)
}

def func[Actual <: HList] = new PartFunc[Actual, f.type] { val poly = f }
```

Or with a regular class :

```
class PartFunc[Actual <: HList, P <: Poly](poly: P) {
  def apply[L1 <: HList](l: L1)(implicit
    mapped: Mapped.Aux[Actual, TypedString, L1],
    mapper: Mapper[P, L1]
  ): mapper.Out = mapper(l)
}

def func[Actual <: HList] = new PartFunc[Actual, f.type](f)
```

Notice that we now have to write `mapper(l)`, because `l map poly` will still look for a `Mapped[poly.type, L1]`.

We can now call `func` :

```
func[
  Int :: String :: HNil
](TypedString[Int]("42") :: TypedString[String]("hello") :: HNil)
// String :: String :: HNil = 42 :: hello :: HNil
```

I am sure that someone with some more in depth knowledge of the Scala type system could provide us with a clearer explanation and possibly a better solution for this problem.

Comment: I asked this question in shapeless gitter room without answer. Thank you for your support.
Which book or articles do you suggest to read to be more familiar with scala types?